Swiss buttercream being runny and unusable for cake decoration
I followed a recipe to make swiss buttercream:
5 egg whites
200 gr sugar
225 gr butter
(Bain-marie to dissolve sugar)
Beating egg whites until stiff peaks form and gradually adding the softened butter 1 tbsp at a time! But it is so runny and there are tiby bits of butter that don't mix no matter how long I keep beating with paddle. How to save this?


I think your egg whites were too cold - butter solidified. Not sure it can be saved but I'll let someone more experienced answer.

I found a very complete Serious Eats troubleshooting article covering the problem you have.
According to the article,

As the frosting's temperature climbs above 75°F (24°C), its butter content will start melting, becoming softer and soupier with every passing degree. When the frosting's temperature drops below 69°F (21°C), its butter content will stiffen, bit by bit, until the frosting breaks into a curdled mess. But between those extremes, when the butter is pliable but cool, the frosting will be silky and light

The solution would be to place the bowl over a steaming water bath until it just starts melting, then move it to a stand mixer and whip it (with the whisk attachment) for about 4 minutes, gradually increasing the speed. Repeat if it's still not glossy and light.
